# wordpress media full control over image uri/path

Tags: wordpress

For a larger amount of images (approx 1k, plus same amount of thumbs, in ca 500 folders), we have the requirement that all image URIs used on the site have to have a SEO optimized path. They are already prepared and present with the complete path structures (each folder contains a thumbs folder with the same filename with smaller size/dimensions).

These are the URIs that we want to achieve:

Full size Image URI: `http://myserver.com/img/de/cats/brown/jimmy.jpg`

Thumb Image URI: `http://myserver.com/img/de/cats/brown/thumbs/jimmy.jpg`

- They shall have an additional path, e.g. **de/cats/brown** in the examples above
- They should start on the root of the domain, i.e. without the `wp-content/uploads/` part of standard wordpress media files.

Simply put: we need full control over the image URIs, i.e. to have their own 'SEO-able' path structure and permalink.

I checked out several Gallery plugins (paid and free) but could not find any documentation on them for the above requirement.

Do you know of any plugin/theme to achieve and manage the URI structure described above?

Comment: I'm actually curious about what kind of SEO expert believes that this is even necessary? Granted, it's an interesting question. But I find it a bit absurd that you would even consider changing the URL pathing to image assets on your server when your search engine rankings are really tailored to what's in your site map (as determined by posts/pages). With that said, I could be entirely mistaken. Does anyone want to shed some light on this?

Comment: Valid comment! One reason for this question is also to gather information on the effects estimated or observed other-where.
For us, it is about SEO in regards to google *image search* (in addition to the normal search). We already have the current version using the same efforts (a plain HTML/static site) and it prooved to be benefitial to have image search results ranked high. Plus, this kind of path and file name provide better readability for the searcher, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add these lines by placing them inside your functions.php file:

```
update_option('upload_url_path', '/wp-content/uploads');
```

This will make WordPress embed images like:

```
src="/wp-content/uploads/fileName.jpg"
```

instead of

```
src="http://domainName.com/wp-content/uploads/fileName.jpg"
```

I hope this can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanx medo0070! Yet, the first part of the URI or the protocol/server part s not as impirtant as the full path. See also my other comment to @deemi. Updated Question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

if you need to change default media upload location,you need to edit the wp-config.php file located in the root directory of your WordPress installation.

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'Your Folder Name' );
```

Remember you can still choose whether or not you want uploaded files to be organized in month/year folders in Settings » Media.

> **Note:** Write this code before this line in wp-config.php

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Hope it may help you

Comment: this does not help me to set the full image, it only removes ther wp-content/uploads part. I still need the image URI to have additional folders. Updated question accordingly.